# How to exclude a certain string in a search pattern

Tags: regular-expressions

There are several exception messages in catalina.out file of tomcat server just like -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

java.lang.RuntimeException

java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

We want to grep all exception error message except “java.io.FileNotFoundException” string.
Tried with below command but it’s not working.

```
cat catalina.out | grep '.*(?<\!=java.io.FileNotFound)Exception\*.)'
```

Can you please help to find out the correct command?

Answer (score 1):

Try a multi-stage grep: `cat <file> | grep Exception | grep -v java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we want single grep command

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate with multiple grep statements as @John suggested in the other answer or for instance use awk e.g.

> awk '/Exception/ && !/java.io.FileNotFoundException/' catalina.out

on your sample this will produce

```
$ awk '/Exception/ && !/java.io.FileNotFoundException/' catalina.out 
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
java.lang.RuntimeException
```

This basically says; match everything that **has** `Exception` string; **and** **NOT** `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we want single grep command

Comment: there is no single grep command to your problem, you would need to combine two at least; one with exclusion, one with inclusion.